# Selenium UI Test pass on local test but fail on VSTS CI

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops

I'm using selenium 3.12.0 + VSTS CI for test automation, and there are some problems that confuse me...I have about 400 test cases in my project, and all tests are passed on local environment, but when I build to the VSTS CI, and start test automatically, it goes wrong.

About 60 test cases are failed when the test run on CI, and these cases are always the same. So I try to build another CI pipeline to test these specific cases which are always failed, and they are passed......

Is there any settings or environments missing? thanks for your reply!

[image]

it seems like the login element can't be caught on the current page, but the same code of the login action runs successfully in other cases, and if this case test independently on another CI pipeline, it works

Comment: @DebanjanB How does that explain what the problem is? Yes it timed out but why when it works in his local runs?

Comment: Can you log into the machine where the runs are happening and watch? Maybe try taking a screenshot on failure so you can see the state of the page. If you run those failing tests 10x, does it fail every time? It may be a timing issue... the runs may be slower on the CI box than your local box. You might need to add some extra time to the waits for it to work consistently.

Comment: @JeffC OK I'll try to take screenshots when it catch an exception. Actually those failed tests only fail when I test all cases, if I test the failed cases on another CI pipeline, they work fine and pass. So I'm thinking about the timing issue too... but the weird point is that CI run faster than local.

Comment: Sounds like you need to take a closer look at what is different between the two pipelines. Are there environment differences? Maybe the machines on the two pipelines have different access levels? Proxy issues? Hard to tell. Going faster is sometimes a problem also but you typically don't have timeout issues when going faster. I think the screenshots are your best shot right now after determining the differences in environment between the two pipelines.

Comment: @JeffC _TimeoutException_ is the outcome of **failed** _ExpectedConditions_. Debug your code through  `findElement()` inconjunction with `Thread.sleep()`. If you are able to locate the element, update the question with your observations so that we can help you out.

Comment: @JeffC First of all you must try to understand the [difference between addressing and answering a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108672/difference-between-addressing-and-answering-a-question). I am yet to construct an answer. Your rantings on several discussion threads are adding no value to the community. Start contributing by providing your answers.

Comment: @DebanjanB You really need to stop talking to others like you're some kind of English expert when you aren't a native speaker and clearly haven't mastered the language. It makes you look confused. You aren't "addressing the question" with comments like, "Isn't the error clear and loud with TimeoutExceptation". Ignoring the spelling and grammar mistakes, you are insulting OP by acting like the answer is obvious yet you haven't provided an answer or anything else of value.

Comment: @JeffC Hi Jeff, I've taken the screenshots and found out that maybe the problem was caused by login information. There's a situation that if two test cases need to login before operate web element, and the case A login fisrt, the browser will catch this login information, so the case B won't find the login button as expected. I've tried to delete all cookies and refresh the current page when the driver launch browsers.

Comment: In this way, the login button will show up, then trigger the click event fine, but the browser still catch the login information of case A, then login automatically. So it won't redirect to the login page...  how can I fix this problem? Or what I can do is group the cases into different categories, and deploy to CI then automatically test these cases by categories in order?